# Using AweCsome Framework to override sharepoint user fields (Author)?

Tags: development

I need to create/update one item in SharePoint using AweCsome Framework (https://github.com/OleAlbers/aweCsome) changing author field.

How can I do this?

When I try to accomplish i define the entity field like this (ex AnyEntityBO):

```
public String Author { get; set; }
```

i got the item, modified author field and save:

```
IAweCsomeTable awecsomeTable = new AweCsomeTable(context);
AnyEntityBO anyEntity= awecsomeTable.SelectItemById<AnyEntityBO>(1);
anyEntity.Author = "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
awecsomeTable.UpdateItem<AnyEntityBO>(anyEntity);
```

When I saved the item I got the error:

```
Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only
```

Help please!

Edit:
Using CSOM and the same context i can chage the author, but i want to use the framework

```
        public static bool UpdateAuthorFieldInListItem(ClientContext context, string listname, int itemid, string loginname)
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List lst = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listname);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem targetListItem = lst.GetItemById(itemid);
            context.Load(targetListItem, item => item["Author"]);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.User user = context.Web.EnsureUser(loginname);
            context.Load(user);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            if (targetListItem != null && user != null)
            {

                targetListItem["Author"] = context.Web.EnsureUser(user.LoginName);
                targetListItem.Update();
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Solution:

Thanks to Denis Molodtsov, point me in the right direction.

I have to declare the field in the entity like this:

```
public KeyValuePair<int, string> Author { get; set; }
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the reason for your error, but you need to be a site collection administrator to change the Author field.

Comment: Thank you, the user have the premissions

Comment: Can this framework update lookup fields and  people fields? Did you try updating something other than Author?

Comment: Thank you, trying it i have got the solution, updated question.